# Finding $S_{n}$ for this geometric series?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

Here is what was given to me:

$t_{1}$ = $\frac {1}{256}$

$r$ = $-4$

$n$ = $10$

The formula I used is $S_{n}$ = $\frac {t_{1} (r^{n} - 1)}{r - 1}$

Here's what I did:

$S_{10}$ = $\frac {\frac{1}{256} (-4^{10} - 1)}{-4 - 1}$

$S_{10}$ = $\frac {\frac{1}{256} (-1048576 - 1)}{-5}$

$S_{10}$ = $\frac {\frac{1}{256} (-1048577)}{-5}$

$S_{10}$ = $-\frac{1048577}{256}$ $\div$ $-\frac{5}{1}$

$S_{10}$ = $\frac{209715}{256}$

in the textbook, the answer is a negative. how???
**I see what I did wrong. Should I always be using the rule mentioned?**

Comment: Note that $r^n = (-4)^{10} \neq - (4^{10})$.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is when you substitute in $r=-4$, because $-4^{10} \ne (-4)^{10}$. You should be using $(-4)^{10}$.

Write it out as $(-4)\times(-4)\times\dots$ ten times and you'll see $(-4)^{10}$ is positive.

Comment: so, should I always be using this rule?

Comment: @mathisn'tmyforte $r^{10}$ is the same thing as $(r)^{10}$. So when you substitute you put $(-4)^{10}$ and when a negative base has an even exponent it's positive and when its odd it's negative. I.e. $(-1)^1=-1$, $(-1)^2=1$, $(-1)^3=-1$, $(-1)^4=1\ldots$

Comment: @math the only "rule" you should be cognizant of is that even powers (like $10$) of real numbers are always non-negative (zero or positive).

Answer (score 2):

In the very first step, you have made a mistake:

It is $(-4)^{10}$ and not $-4^{10}$

Answer (score 1):

Given:
$t_{1}$ = $\frac {1}{256}$
$r$ = $-4$
$n$ = $10$
$S_{n} = \frac {t_{1} (r^{n} - 1)}{r - 1}$
then $(-4)^{10} = (-1)^{10} \cdot 1048576 = 1048576$ and
\begin{align}
S_{10} &= \frac{1}{256} \, \frac{(-4)^{10} - 1}{-4 -1} \\
&= \frac{1}{256} \, \frac{1048575}{-5} = - \frac{209715}{256}
\end{align}